# Selenium WebDriver считывание популярных поисковых запросов

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

необходимо написать код по примерному алгоритму: Значение текстового поля одного из элементов формы записывается в поисковую строку браузера, раскрывающийся список популярных запросов на эту тему должен считываться и заноситься списком в другой элемент формы. Используя Selenium WebDriver. Не откажусь еще от информации, как открывать каждую ссылку в новой вкладке через selenium, и можно ли скрыть во время выполнения операции консоль?

```
IEnumerable<string> GetGoogleSuggestions(string query)
          {
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
                IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
                element.SendKeys(query);
                WaitForReady(driver, "form div div div ul span");        
                var links = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("form div div div ul span"));
                return links.Select(l => l.GetAttribute("innerText")).ToArray();

                void WaitForReady(IWebDriver webDriver, string elementSelector)
                {
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(elementSelector)).Count > 0);
                }

                foreach (var s in GetGoogleSuggestions("selenium webdriver"))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = s;
                }  
          }
```

Comment: у вас уже какой то код есть и с ним какие то проблемы или вы просите написать код для вас?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как обратиться к этому выпадающему списку в гугле или в яндексе. У меня есть код только на открытие определенного сайта (яндекс маркет) и поиск по нему заданного текста

Comment: Так что кода именно с таким алгоритмом не имеется

Comment: какие то доки/статьи читали? Что то [гуглили](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+c%23+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)?

Comment: Гуглил конечно, смотрел на ютубе несколько обучалок, по ним и сделал поиск на двух сайтах, открытие в разных окнах. Свою проблему не нашел

Comment: Ну [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17208089/312041), например. Оно?

Comment: После вашего коммента решил на англе погуглить и тоже нашел эту ссыль) буду пробовать сейчас

Comment: Не находит элементы по тем id что в том ответе даны By.Id("gbqfq"), открыл сам посмотреть, id у поиска вообще нет, обратился по имени класса - тоже ошибка, получилось обратиться к строке поиска только по By.Name("q"), но дальше к самому списку так и не получается

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста с обращением к элементам списка, если можете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вообще с селениумом не работаю, потому могу что то сделать неверно, но вот что получилось

```
IEnumerable<string> GetGoogleSuggestions(string query)
{
    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\tym32\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\"))
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        element.SendKeys(query);

        WaitForReady(driver, "form div div div ul span");

        var links = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("form div div div ul span"));
        return links.Select(l => l.GetAttribute("innerText")).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Метод для ожидания подсказок на странице

```
void WaitForReady(IWebDriver webDriver, string elementSelector)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(elementSelector)).Count > 0);
}
```

Использовать вот так

```
foreach(var s in  GetGoogleSuggestions("selenium webdriver"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Потыкал, вроде стабильно находит что надо. Для поиска нужных селекторов использовал Chrome - инстпрументы разработчика.

Comment: указывает что foreach - недостижимый код.
еще я удалил путь к драйверу, он ведь уже есть в проекте IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
Вследствие этого появилась ошибка в использовании driver тут wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(elementSelector)).Count > 0);

Comment: @KudaIPopal то есть вы взяли мой код, куда то скопировали, что то поменяли, выскочила какая то ошибка, и вы мне предлагаете и ошибку угадать и код, что у вас получился? :)

Comment: Пытался добавить код, но по объему не вмещается

Comment: @KudaIPopal весь код добавляйте в вопрос

Comment: добавил код, ошибка в строке wait.Until(driver => driver(локальная переменная или параметр и именем "driver" нельзя объявить в данной области, т.к. это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра)

Comment: @KudaIPopal зачем вы всё в кучу намешали? Я вам не такой код показал, что вы написали. Сделайте так, как у меня.

Comment: Извините меня, я такой болван, вписал все внутрь GetGoogleSuggestions :)

Comment: @KudaIPopal ничего страшного, главное, что всё получилось.

Comment: скажите только, как в query задать свое значение?

Comment: @KudaIPopal `GetGoogleSuggestions("своё значение")`

Comment: Благодарю) я пытался string query = richTextBox1.text; перед конструкцией всей написать)

Comment: @KudaIPopal можно и так `string query = richTextBox1.text;  .... foreach(var s in  GetGoogleSuggestions(query ){...}`

Comment: а как бы так сделать, чтобы каждая строка записывалась в combobox

Comment: все, сделал, comboBox1.Items.Add(s);

Comment: Не откажусь еще от информации, как открывать каждую ссылку в новой вкладке через selenium, и можно ли скрыть во время выполнения операции консоль?

Comment: @KudaIPopal я думаю, что это 2 отдельных вопроса, у меня уже нет времени искать для вас ответы :)

Comment: Хорошо, я и так вам безумно благодарен) Но для занудства скажу, что они были изначально включены в вопрос)

Comment: @KudaIPopal да, но смотрите как работает сайт - вы задаете вопрос, кто то отвечает, вы получаете ответ, а кто то плюсики. Потому задавая несколько вопросов в одном, отвечающий дожен ответить  на каждй из них, но плюсиков получит как за один ответ. Потому тут принято задавать один вопрос на вопрос. Мне конечно это не сильно важно, у меня плюсиков и так много, но задавая отдельно вопросы вы другим даёте шанс заработать кармы + ваши вопросы по отдельности получат больше внимания.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, учту)