# Топ лучших способов обработки ошибки "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException" при работе c Selenium на C# / .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, xpath, chromedriver

Когда мы пытаемся получить **IWebElement**, но он ещё не прогрузился или его не существует на странице, то получаем ошибку ***"OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:"***, после чего программа прерывается.

 Мне не нравится подход, когда все это оборачиваем в trу catch, так же не нравится подход когда вызываем Thread.Sleep (так как теряем скорость + интернет или сервер может быть разной конфигурации, где-то 1с хватит все прогрузить, а иногда и 5с не хватит).

 Если у проекта стоит задача в минимальное количество времени выполнить автоматизацию на сайте, то какое решение будет наилучшим? Чтобы это было быстро, красиво и правильно.
Исходя из этого 3 вопроса:

1. Может стоит посмотреть в сторону выполнения JavaScript с
   помощью Selenium WebDriver in C#?
2. Кто пользуется какими инструментами при решении этой задачи?
3. Может кто-то даже может подсказать или поделиться своими наработками?

Comment: Для чего вам селениум? Вы тестируете свой сайт? Или парсите чужой? Если 2-е, то вам селениум в 99% случаев не нужен вовсе, достаточно простого `HttpClient`.

Comment: Хорошие наблюдения, спасибо что поделились, а зачем это всё?

Comment: `пытаемся получить IWebElement` как это в коде выглядит?

Comment: Ну если он не прогризился, а можно получить нотификацию о том, что прогрузился, и в этот момент продолжить обработку?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ чужой, простой HttpClient тут не подходит, нужно именно силами селениума.

Comment: @tym32167 ну к примеру даже вот так если: 
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathElement));

Comment: чем [wait.until](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985437/179763) не нравится? (если что, я в селениуме полный ноль)

Comment: @Mipofler Как вы поняли, что "не подходит"?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну например если на странице динамические элементы.
Или если задача именно в том, чтобы сделать имитацию реального пользователя.

Comment: @Mipofler HTML - это UI, а за кулисами почти любого сайта, при помощи JS отправляются простые POST/GET запросы на конкретные адреса, так UI общается с сервером, и вот вам уже и динамика. Нажмите F12 и смотрите во вкладке "Сеть" то, что отправляется, с этим вы и должны работать. Имитация пользователя - даже полноценный браузер с этим не поможет, а банальные задержки и подмена данных - опять же, простые Http запросы через `HttpClient`. Так что, вы точно уверены, что вам нужен полноценный браузер для решения вашей задачи?) Повторю, в 99% случаей ответ **нет**.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну если представим что у нас как раз 1%, то как лучше обработать?

Comment: @Mipofler Ну вам выше несколько наводящих вопросов задали по селениуму. А мое личное мнение - инструменты надо использовать для того, для чего они были созданы, серениум же был создан для QA, то есть автоматизации тестирования, но не парсинга чужого сайта.